# Let $T:K\to E$ be linear. Prove that exists a unique $m\in E$ such that $T(x)=xm$ for all $x\in K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $T:K\to E$ be linear. Prove that exists a unique $m\in E$ such that $T(x)=xm$ for all $x\in K$

I dont understand this exercise. Here $K$ is a field (and a vector space over itself) and $E$ a vector space over $K$.

If $x$ is a vector, and due to the fact that $m$ is a vector, I must assume that $E$ is an algebra? Because the vector product $xm$ is assumed in the question.

If $x$ is an scalar then cause $T$ is linear I must assume that $T(x)=xT(1)$?

Any hint or lighting will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It looks to me like $x$ is a scalar (the question says $x\in K$ after all), and there is nothing deeper going on than $T(x)=T(x\cdot 1)=xT(1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write $T(1)=m, T(x)=T(x.1)=xT(1)=xm$